# How to shift a string to right in python?

Tags: python

I tried shifting a string to right

- the last value should be the first and the rest follows
- `s= "I Me You"` should return `"You I Me"`

I tried the following code but it doesn't work please help me out..

```
sr= "I Me You"
def shift_right(sr):
    L=sr.split()
    new_list=L[-1]

    new_list= new_list.append(1,L[:0])
    return (new_list)

print(shift_right(sr)
print (shift_reverse(sr))
```

Comment: Your first problem is a missing parenthesis on the line `print(shift_right(sr)`. Your second problem is that `append` modifies a list a list in place, you don't need the `new_list=`.

Answer (score 10):

And now ...

### Contest time

Maybe what is more interesting is *what is the faster approach?*.

First test by the OP test string (just 3 chunks) and the second test by a string of 600 one char chunks.

```
from collections import deque
import timeit

def trivial(s):
    l = s.split()
    return ' '.join(l[-1:] + l[:-1])

def more_split(s):
    return ' '.join([s.split()[-1]] + s.split()[:-1])

def dq(s):
    s_deq = deque(s.split())
    s_deq.rotate(1)
    return ' '.join(s_deq)

def find_and_slice(s):
    lsi = s.rfind(' ')
    return s[lsi+1:] + ' ' + s[:lsi]

def rs_lazy(s):
    return ' '.join(reversed(s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)))

def rs_smart(s):
    rs = s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
    return rs[1] + ' ' + rs[0]

def rpart(s):
    part = s.rpartition(' ')
    return part[-1] + part[1] + part[0]

def time_a_method(m, s):
    c_arg = "('{}')".format(s)
    t = timeit.timeit(m + c_arg, setup="from __main__ import " + m , number=100000)
    print( m + " "*(15-len(m)) + "----> {}".format(t))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(trivial("I Me You"))
    print(more_split("I Me You"))
    print(dq("I Me You"))
    print(find_and_slice("I Me You"))
    print(rs_lazy("I Me You"))
    print(rs_smart("I Me You"))
    print(rpart("I Me You"))
    print("######## USE: 'I Me You'")
    for m in ["trivial", "more_split", "dq", "find_and_slice", "rs_lazy", "rs_smart", "rpart"]:
        time_a_method(m, "I Me You")

    print("######## USE: 'a b c d e f '*100")
    s = 'a b c d e f '*100
    for m in ["trivial", "more_split", "dq", "find_and_slice", "rs_lazy", "rs_smart", "rpart"]:
        time_a_method(m, s)
```

That give follow results:

> ```
> You I Me
> You I Me
> You I Me
> You I Me
> You I Me
> You I Me
> You I Me
> ######## USE: 'I Me You'
> trivial        ----> 0.1339518820000194
> more_split     ----> 0.1532761280000159
> dq             ----> 0.182199565000019
> find_and_slice ----> 0.07563322400005745
> rs_lazy        ----> 0.23457759100006115
> rs_smart       ----> 0.1615759960000105
> rpart          ----> 0.06102836100001241
> ######## USE: 'a b c d e f '*100
> trivial        ----> 3.2239098259999537
> more_split     ----> 4.6946649449999995
> dq             ----> 3.991058845999987
> find_and_slice ----> 0.15106809200005955
> rs_lazy        ----> 0.32278001499992115
> rs_smart       ----> 0.22939544400003342
> rpart          ----> 0.10590313199998036
> ```

And the *winner* is.....

```
def rpart(s):
    part = s.rpartition(' ')
    return part[-1] + part[1] + part[0]
```

That surprised me (I bet on `find_and_slice` and I lost). There are 2 answers classes:

1. brute force: split all string
2. take care that we need just the last part of the string

Even in the simplest case `I Me You` the first approach is from 2 to 3 time slower than the best one. Obviously when the string become more interesting the first approach become really inefficient.

The real funny thing is that the most voted answer is the slower :)

Comment: Nice benchmark! This tells me I should use rpartition more. It seems that rpartition creates an extra tuple object, which has a cost, but the cost is apparently less than the cost of doing two explicit slices in Python.

Comment: I have updated the rsplit solution to something that I believe will be faster than using join and reversed. It's more similar to the rfind and partition answers now.

Comment: @Shashank Updated... but it don't change the final results.

Comment: Yes I know, I already ran it myself, rpartition and rfind are still clearly the fastest, but I think it's still interesting to see how something can be 1.5x faster by avoiding the use of reversed and join.

Answer (score 6):

First we split the string:

```
>>> s = "I Me You"
>>> l = s.split()
>>> l
['I', 'Me', 'You']
```

Then we add `l[-1:]`, which is the list from the last element to the end, with `l[:-1]`, which is the list from the start until (but not containing) the last element:

```
>>> l[-1:] + l[:-1]
['You', 'I', 'Me']
```

Finally we join:

```
>>> ' '.join(l[-1:] + l[:-1])
'You I Me'
```

Answer (score 2):

Faster solution using [`str.rfind`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind), string slice, and string concatenation:

```
>>> s = 'I Me You'
>>> lsi = s.rfind(' ')
>>> s[lsi+1:] + ' ' + s[:lsi]
'You I Me'
```

Another fast solution with [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
>>> rs = s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
>>> rs[1] + ' ' + rs[0]
'You I Me'
```

In function forms:

```
def find_and_slice(s):
    lsi = s.rfind(' ')
    return s[lsi+1:] + ' ' + s[:lsi]

def rs(s):
    rs = s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
    return rs[1] + ' ' + rs[0]
```

Comment: That's not the expected output.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Thanks for notifying, I have fixed it to give the right output.

Answer (score 2):

If you make the string a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque), then you can use the [`rotate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) method:

```
from collections import deque

s = 'I Me You'
s_deq = deque(s.split())
s_deq.rotate(1)
print ' '.join(s_deq)
#OUT: You I Me
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do that without using lists if all separators are same (`split` without parameters accepts all whitespace characters). Use string methods like `rindex` or `rpartition`:

```
 >>> part = s.rpartition(' ')
 >>> part[-1] + part[1] + part[0]
 'You I Me'
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for you

```
def shift_str(s):
    arr = s.split()
    first = arr.pop(0)
    arr.append(first)
    return " ".join(arr)
```

E.g:

`shift_str("xxx ccc lklklk")` >> `'ccc lklklk xxx'`

Comment: It is wrong the OP ask the right shift and not left

Answer (score 1):

You can use indices and slices to create a new list which you then join by spaces:

```
print(' '.join([s.split()[-1]] + s.split()[:-1])) # You I Me
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "I Me You"

In [2]: s.rsplit(None, 1)[-1] + ' ' + s.rsplit(None, 1)[0]
Out[3]: "You I Me"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.pop()`

```
def shift(lst, side):
    if side == "left":
        a = lst.pop(0)
        return lst + [a]
    elif side == "right":
        a = lst.pop()
        return [a] + lst
    raise ValueError("Side is incorrect: " + side)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def shift_right(sr):
    L = sr.split()
    return ' '.join([L[-1]]+L[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
string = 'this is a test string'
new_str = string.split() #The .split() method splits a string into a list
new_str[0],new_str[-1] = new_str[-1], new_str[0] #this is where python gets so amazing
print ' '.join(new_str) #just join the list again
```

Output

```
'string is a test this'
```